# Pass ng-template through component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable

PrimeNG Table takes body and header templates to render the table. I have created the component that wraps PrimeNG table. How can I pass ng-template through my component to p-table?

Answer (score 1):

The PrimeNG [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) shows this nicely. E.g.

```
<p-table [value]="cars">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of cols">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
                    {{car[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Here you can see the *body* and *header* templates are marked using the `pTemplate` Directive.
The `p-table` will be able to pick them up and use them via `ng-container` and the structural Directive `ngTemplateOutlet`.

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/a550abe089a703fdfade96a9a491c2e6c1465720/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L281).

```
@ContentChildren(PrimeTemplate) templates: QueryList<PrimeTemplate>;
```

Comment: But the `p-table` will be declared in his custom component, and the `header` and `body` templates will be declared in the parent component. How will he do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ng-content` to pass html code to your component

consider this code as a custom component

```
<div> 
 <ng-content> </ng-content>
</div>
```

and now we use it

```
<custom-component>
whatever is written here will be placed where ng content is 
</custom-component>
```

Comment: are you sure that it is working way? doesn't work for me

Comment: Yes you can see the refrence here https://angular.io/api/core/ng-content